# Express Path matching too far

Tags: javascript, express

I'm having a problem, which I swear I've had before, but i'm not sure where.

in app.js

```
app.use('/admin', admin);
```

in admin.js

```
// generic setup stuff
router.get('/', function(req, res){ res.send('hello'); });
router.get('/login', function(req, res){ res.send('goodbye'); });
```

But, no matter what I try, any request to `/admin/login` only prints

> hello

If I remove the `/` handler from `admin.js`, I get

> goodbye

as I'd expect.

Edit: I've tried modifying the order that the endpoints appear in.  It still fails.

Comment: Have you restarted the application after modifying the routes?

Comment: @Vohuman I have, yes.

Comment: I'm uncertain about the cause, but you can try reordering the '/login' in front of '/' route. This is usually necessary only if the first route indeed matches more than necessary (with the use of wildcards/RegExp)

Comment: @kazenorin I have tried that, too.

Comment: I'm sure the problem is something else. I always mount routers that way in express and haven't had any problems.

Comment: Then it's most probably related to something that's not available in your question. My guess its some initaiization stuff or middleware conflict.

Comment: you're right.  i had a bug before that I fixed, which put an extra route in and broke it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the route to the **root** at last. otherwise any request can match up with `router.get('/',(req, res) =>{});` and you will only get the response in root route.

try following,

```
router.get('/login', function(req, res){ res.send('goodbye'); });
router.get('/', function(req, res){ res.send('hello'); });
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't fix it either.

Comment: Normally ExpressJS doesn't work that way, '/' and '/login' are different routes. You need reordering only if you have a route like '/*' which is a superset of '/login'